# create subdomain via php script on mediatemple hosting

Tags: php, mediatemple

I am new to MediaTemple hosting.
All I need to create subdomain which will open main site so no need to create any files or folder for subdomain. So domain and subdomains will show same content from same source.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any useful information. I have successfully created subdomain via php script on HostGator hosting from below function. But now I want to create subdomain via php script on MediaTemple hosting.

```
public function create_subdomain($subDomain,$cPanelUser,$cPanelPass,$rootDomain,$subDomainDir) 
    {
        $buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=" . $subDomainDir;

        $openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
        if(!$openSocket) {
            return "Socket error";
            exit();
        }

        $authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
        $authPass = base64_encode($authString);
        $buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
        $buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
        $buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
        $buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

        fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
        while(!feof($openSocket)) {
        fgets($openSocket,128);
        }
        fclose($openSocket);

        $newDomain = "http://" . $subDomain . "." . $rootDomain . "/";

        return "Created subdomain $newDomain";

    }
```